# jquery.js?v=1.9.1:4421 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

i have a dropdown menu with some submenus. When I click one li item, jquery should add a class to the closest ul to leave the ul open. But when I click one li item, it redirects to a new webpage. How to remember the added class after site refresh?

I have tried this:

```
 jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#mobile-menu').on('click', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', jQuery(e.target).closest('ul').addClass('leave-open'));
    });
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {

        jQuery(lastTab).addClass('leave-open');
    }
});
```

But my console say:

jquery.js?v=1.9.1:4421 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Can somebody help me?

Thx

Comment: use $(this) instead of jQuery(e.target)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is using an object as a selector.

Indeed, the lastTab variable don't return the selector but the JQuery object associated with the selected element.

So you should do instead :

```
lastTab.addClass('leave-open')
```

By the way, please start using the `$`
alias instead of `jQuery` for readability